# Limiting non premium users to write to firebase database only once a day

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to limit my non premium users to only post one post per day. Premium users have no limit. I am unclear how to set up my database rules. At the moment I have only validated users can post to the database. *note I want to write to the AddPost node*

My database Json looks like this:

```
User :
   uid:
      verified : true
      premium : false
```

And my rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
  "AddPost": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": 
"root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('verified').val() == true"
 }  
    ,"Users": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
    }
    ,"FavoritedBusinesses": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
    }
    ,"Geolocs": {
       ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
    }
    ,"ReviewPost": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }
     ,"Views": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }

   }


}
```

MY SOLUTION
So using Franks guidance I was able to string some rules together. As a base rule every user must be verified so I put this in the "validate" condition as its a common denominator.. then in the write first we check to see if the user is a premium if it returns false then we check the last time stamp from the one we stored in the last post. However if the first condition fails then that means the user is infact premium and should be allowed to post..

new database rules

```
".write": "root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('premium').val() 
=== false && (newData.parent().child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('lastPostStamp').val() === now) && (newData.parent().child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('lastPostStamp').val() > root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('lastPostStamp').val() + 24*60*60*1000) || root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('premium').val() === true ",
        ".validate": "root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('verified').val() === true"
```

Comment: This isn't standard logic that would be written into the firebase rules. You have to write the logic yourself in the app. which means you'd need to track when a non premium user write to that object and record the time they done it, then make a decision based on that info

Comment: I thought maybe that’s what I would have to do but wanted to see if there was a possibility to write security rules .

Comment: not sure, I don't think so. but you'd have to research it, im not very familiar with firebase authentication, but usually custom logic like this goes in your app

Comment: I think your right. I’m currently doing exactly what you stated. Using userdefaults.

Comment: Agree with @Scriptable, this should be done in your app logic, not a database rule.

Comment: If anyone wants to give me an example of doing this with string values and userdefaults I will accept the answer as to not leave this open as comments :)

Comment: This can be done, but the rule will have to make clever use of server timestamps, and possible multi-location updates if the write location isn't the same every time.  The trick is to require the client to send a timestamp, validate that it's always "now" in the rule, and check the different between the given timestamp and the last one written.

Comment: The cleanest way to do this might be to write a Cloud Function to make sure that the proper users are able to write: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/. That way the logic is offloaded from the app and can change if need be, but is more flexible than writing logic inside of your Database Rules.

Comment: I have never used cloud functions before I have read this documentation and Im still a little unsure as to how I can employ this. @AlexMason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Doug commented, this is possible by:

- Requiring that each time the user writes a post, they also write a timestamp to a known location (say `/Users/$uid/last_post_timestamp`).
- Validating that they can only write `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to that location.
- Validating that they can only write a new post when the current value in `/Users/$uid/last_post_timestamp` is at least one day ago.

So you'd need something along these lines in the rules for the new post:

```
(newData.parent().child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('last_post_timestamp').val()
   === now) && 
(newData.parent().child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('last_post_timestamp').val()
   > root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('last_post_timestamp').val() + 24*60*60*1000)
```

Comment: This makes sense ! Nice. However, how would I differentiate between a premium user and a non premium ? I see here “validating that they can only write a new post when current value is less than one day ago” but I only want this functionality for users that don’t have premium accounts inside my app.. could I just add another rule onto this looking into the user node for a premium value?  The issue is I have so many rules ..

Comment: I would need if user is premium then allow a normal write with no limits, if not then do the checks you state above. @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: That sounds like an or (`||`) around this condition. So `root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('premium').val() === true || ...`.

Comment: So if it is a premium user allow to post or if it’s not premium then check for the last post stamp to see if it’s greater than 24 hrs.. I thought the || meant and including.. but it doesn’t? It means or ? So this would essentially be like an if statement in swift ? In the essence once one condition is fulfilled the other is ignored  @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: The `||` is an **or** operator. So the expression evaluates to `true` if either side of the `||` is `true`. So `false || false == false`, `false || true == true`, `true || false == true` and `true || true == true`. If you're new to boolean logic, I highly recommend trying it out in your code. In Swift the `||` works the same.

Comment: ".write": "root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('verified').val() === true || root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('premium').val() === true || root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('verified').val() === true || root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('premium').val() === false || (newData.parent().child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('lastPostStamp').val() === now) && (newData.parent().child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('lastPostStamp').val() > root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('lastPostStamp').val() + 24*60*60*1000)"

Comment: This is what I have and Ive tested it however I can still post from a non premium account and post back to back posts.. I think Im missing something here..  to me it seems the rules arent seperate.. Im not too sure on the syntax here.. but something is wrong@FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I think this may also be because  we allow writing to the "User" node still.. essentially updating the lastPostStamp value could this be it? This is much more complex than I originally thought..

Comment: If you test with only the condition for non-premium users, does it work for those. I.e. can those users then post once per day? If not, first fix that. If that works, move on the *just* the premium users and get that to work. Once both work in isolation, combine the two conditions with an `||`.

Comment: Ok so I did what you suggested. And refined some things and I will post an answer as to what worked for me as well as accepting yours because it is what lead me to the answer!